# GlassMapper Render Custom Link Field

Tags: razor, sitecore, glass-mapper, sitecore8.1

We are on sitecore 8.1 update 3 and Glass Mapper 4.2.1.188

For normal Link field its working fine in experienced editor and normal mode.

We have duplicated General Link field in core database and removed "Javascript" menu item. That's the only change we have made for custom Link field.

This makes field disappeared in experience editor mode. Its fine in normal mode.

```
@RenderLink(x => x.CallToActionButton, new { @class = "c-btn c-btn--strong c-btn--large" }, isEditable: true)
```

Edit 1:

when i use Sitecore Field renderer its all good.

```
 @Html.Sitecore().Field(FieldIds.HomeCallToActionButton, new { @class = "c-btn c-btn--strong c-btn--large" })
```

Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason of you problem is that Sitecore checks the field type key while generating the code which is displayed in Experience Editor.

`Sitecore.Pipelines.RenderField.GetLinkFieldValue` class checks if the field type key is either `link` or `general link` and from what you wrote, you had copied original `General Link` field so your name of the field is `Custom Link` or something like that. Which means that field type key is `custom link` in your case (field type name lowercase). `SkipProcessor` method compares `custom link` with field type key, and because it's different, processor ignores your field.

You cannot simply rename your field to `General Link` and put it under `Field Types/Custom` folder cause Sitecore doesn't keep id of the field type (it stores field type key instead).

What you can do is override `Sitecore.Pipelines.RenderField.GetLinkFieldValue` class and one of its method like that:

```cs
using Sitecore.Pipelines.RenderField;

namespace My.Assembly.Namespace
{
    public class GetLinkFieldValue : Sitecore.Pipelines.RenderField.GetLinkFieldValue
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Checks if the field should not be handled by the processor.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="args">The arguments.</param>
        /// <returns>true if the field should not be handled by the processor; otherwise false</returns>
        protected override bool SkipProcessor(RenderFieldArgs args)
        {
            if (args == null)
                return true;
            string fieldTypeKey = args.FieldTypeKey;
            if (fieldTypeKey == "custom link")
                return false;
            return base.SkipProcessor(args);
        }
    }
}
```

and register it instead of the original class:

```xml
<sitecore>
  <pipelines>
    <renderField>
        <processor type="Sitecore.Pipelines.RenderField.GetLinkFieldValue, Sitecore.Kernel">
           <patch:attribute name="type">My.Assembly.Namespace.GetLinkFieldValue, My.Assembly</patch:attribute>
        </processor>
    </renderField>
  </pipelines>
</sitecore>
```

Comment: @marek-Musieklak Sitecore is rendering the field right. When i use Sitecore Field helper.Its all good in Experience editor. Its only happens with GlassMapper?

Comment: Also what is FieldTypeKey?

Comment: Field Type Key = Field Type Name lowercase. Have you tried what I wrote above?

Comment: I have not tried the way u suggested because sitecore Field helper is rendering it right? Please see my edit in question.

Comment: Glass uses exactly what I pasted above in it's background. Try the solution above.

Comment: worked! But one last question. "You cannot simply rename your field to General Link and put it under Field Types/Custom folder cause Sitecore doesn't keep id of the field type (it stores field type key instead)." Sitecore doesn't keep id what do u mean by that? I tried changing name to "General Link" and it didnot worked like u said but did not understand why?

Comment: where can i find how its storing?

Comment: I tried with General Link with search and it worked? How does that work? as its fieldTypeKey="general link with search" this should be skipped? but working?

Comment: In Sitecore content tree find the template which uses `CallToActionButton` field. Expand it and find the `CallToActionButton` item itself. Switch to raw values and dheck its `Type` field. It's only the `General Link` text (or your custom field name) instead of id of the field in core database. In terms of `General field with search` - I don't know. Would have to debug it but you can do same thing :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128845/discussion-between-dheeraj-palagiri-and-marek-musielak).